# Google Now widget shadow color code?

Tags: android, google-now

What is the color code (including transparency) of the Google Now widget's shadow?

Widget:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The shade I use looks really similar

```
\#D3D3D3
```

And transparency in android xml just put an 80 after the #

```
\#80D3D3D3
```